# How to search in one NumPy array for positions for getting at these position the value from a second NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, arcgis, arcpy

I have two `raster` files which I have converted into `NumPy` arrays (`arcpy.RasterToNumpyArray`) to work with the values in the `raster` cells with Python.

One of the `raster` has two values `True` and `False`. The other `raster` has different values in the range between `0` to `1000`. Both `rasters` have exactly the same extent, so both `NumPy` arrays are build up identically (columns and rows), except the values.

My aim is to identify all positions in `NumPy` array `A` which have the value `True`. These positions shall be used for getting the value at these positions from `NumPy` array `B`.

Do you have any idea how I can implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your description right, you should just be able to do `B[A]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array with `True` and `False` values to simply index into the other. Here's a sample:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = np.array([[True,False,False],[False,True,False],[False,False,True]])
a[b] ## gives  array([1, 5, 9])
```